# Maven dependencies and Netbeans8

Tags: maven, netbeans

I am working from Netbeans-8 & Maven.
I've never worked with Maven before...

I am building two projects. Project1 is a dependency of Project2.

If I make changes in both project1 & project2, and "build with dependencies" project2 then:
Project2 is linked with an old version of project1!

I happen to change project1 alot. Before using maven in my IDE, I was used that building a dependent project, also builds it's dependencies. I mean that's what dependencies in a build system is all about...

How do I fix this, so that "build with dependencies" on project2 also builds project1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your dependency version needs to match the version of the project you depend on.  Then you also need to have both projects in one reactor (include both projects as modules in one parent project). Then Build with dependencies should work with maven 3 at least.

You haven't mentioned what type of projects use (packaging) but please note that with Compile on Save turned on, you often don't need to do rebuilds of the changed projects.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding pacakging: one of my projects is a war file which includes another project which is a jar file. I am assuming that i need the reactor in the war file?

Comment: I believe just running/redeploying the war project should be mostly enough but I don't have direct experience with it.